# how to get the length of every element in one column

Tags: python, pandas

In csv file, there is one column called "no_pun". There are some tokenized words in it. I want to get the length of every element in this column. This is easy in python. But I have an error.

My code:

```
for i in range(0,len(data['no_pun'])):
    data["len_desc"][i] = len(data["no_pun"][i])
```

---

The KeyError:

```
  KeyError Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2655             try:
-> 2656                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2657             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'len_desc'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Please format you code using four space indentation for readability.

Comment: I'm sorry. This is my first time to ask a question in stackoverflow...

Comment: Try to simplify the example. Maybe extract one line from the csv or something. Also, it looks like the problem is in the lookup of the key `len_desc`, are you sure it is present in the object? All in all, if you want help it's best if you provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Can you provide a dummy sample of the content of column 'no_pun' and what expected results you would like? By all cost avoid loops when using Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to try and assign a value to a key in a list that does not exist, in this case len_desc.

Investigate the contents of data and see if all items have a len_desc key, I expect at least one to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

The `data["len_desc"]` is probably not initialized to be a list. You may want to set it first before you run your function. However, a better way to do this would be using [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python): `data["len_desc"] = [len(data) for data in data["no_pun"]]`

Comment: Thank you ! This works for me. But I don't understand why I should set it as a list. data['len_desc'] should be a str

Comment: The part data['len_desc'] creates a column named 'len_desc' to the the dataframe data, where the list would be saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` method to use the function on every row of your column and save it on a new column in your dataframe called 'a'.

```
data['a'] = data['no_pun'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

If you need to iterate with a for loop and save to a new column, you can use iteritems(). First, you will need to create a column with a dummy number.

```
data['b'] = 0#dummy column creation
for index, row in data['no_pun'].iteritems():#loop
     data['b'][index] = len(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would add a new column to the existing dataframe that has the length of the string from `no_pun` column:

```
data['NewColumnName'] = [len(x) for x in data['no_pun']]
```

or

```
data['no_pun'].str.len()
```